# python win32ui and win32printer to set page size and printer printing

Tags: python, pywin32, win32ui

printing set it cant work,the code can printing out but size have not change,Exception capture does not show any prompts，i hope to get some help,and also i have a question,printing requires running the code with administrator privileges,
If I package it into an exe, do I still need administrator rights for printing?
I' ve looked around，However, the method found is c# or c++. The file printed only using win32printer shows an error and cannot be browsed, and the content is 0kb.
Thanks in advance.

```
import win32con
import win32print
import win32ui

def pdf_print_device():
    try:
        default_printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
        printdefaults = {"DesiredAccess": win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS}
        handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(default_printer, printdefaults)

        try:
            properties = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2)
            devmode = properties['pDevMode']
            devmode.PaperLength = 1000
            devmode.PaperWidth = 1000
            devmode.Orientation = win32con.DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE
            properties['pDevMode'] = devmode
            win32print.SetPrinter(handle, 2, properties, 0)
            win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(default_printer)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        text = "test"

        hdc = win32ui.CreateDC()
        hdc.CreatePrinterDC(default_printer)
        hdc.StartDoc("test")

        title = [150, 400, text, {'name': 'Times New Roman', 'height': 135}]
        font = win32ui.CreateFont(title[3])
        hdc.SelectObject(font)
        hdc.TextOut(title[0], title[1], str(title[2]))

        hdc.EndPage()
        hdc.EndDoc()
        win32print.ClosePrinter(handle)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdf_print_device()
```

i hope can change the printer page size